# Applying two styler functions simultanesouly to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Here is the example script I am working with. I am trying to apply two styler functions to a dataframe at the same time but as you can see, it would only call the colors2 function. What would be the best way to apply two functions at the same time?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-100,500,400,0,222,222], [9000,124,0,-147,54,-56],[77,0,110,211,0,222], [111,11,-600,33,0,22,],[213,-124,0,-147,54,-56]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y','z'], list('ab')])

def colors(i):
    if i > 0:
        return 'background: red'
    elif i < 0:
        return 'background: green'
    elif i == 0:
        return 'background: yellow'
    else:
        ''
def colors2(i):
    if i < 0:
        return 'background: red'
    elif i > 0:
        return 'background: green'
    elif i == 0:
        return 'background: yellow'
    else:
        ''
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.style.applymap (colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, idx['x','b']])
df.style.applymap (colors2, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, idx[:, 'b']])
```

[image]

Comment: What `idx` refers to ?

Comment: Hi abokey, it's ```idx = pd.IndexSlice``` I've updated my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain your `applymap` commands in the desired order (last one prevails):

```
(df.style
   .applymap(colors2, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'b']])
   .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice['x','b']])
 )
```

Here `pd.IndexSlice['x','b']]` is more restrictive than `pd.IndexSlice[:, 'b']` so we use it last.

Another option could be to use a single function and to decide the color based on the labels inside it.

```
import numpy as np
def colors(s):
    if s.name[0] == 'x':
        s = s*-1
    return np.sign(s).map({-1: 'background: red', 1: 'background: green', 0: 'background: yellow'})
     
(df.style
   .apply(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'b']])
 )
```

Output:

[image: pandas multiple styles]

Comment: wow! That's much easier than I thought. Thank you so much, mozway. I wasn't aware you could do that. Do you mind sharing where to learn what you've shown me? Also, I am sure there would be a better way to make two functions into one, do you know a better way to make it a single function

Comment: See update for a single function

Comment: Yea, awesome work! Works flawlessly. I like it better than the first one. I may need to dig into it a bit more to get myself more comfortable with it. Could you share a good documentation for me to look into?

Comment: I don't use any documentation other than the pandas official one ;)